# How geostrategically important is the Maldives to China?

Tags: china, geopolitics, maldives

> India has said its military personnel were stationed in the Maldives
> to maintain and operate two rescue and reconnaissance helicopters and
> a small aircraft it had donated years ago. Removing Indian troops was
> an election promise made by Mr Muizzu, who came to power in November.
>
> India has long wielded influence over the Maldives, whose strategic
> location in its backyard allowed it to monitor a crucial part of the
> Indian Ocean. But the relationship between the countries has soured
> over the past few months, partly due to Mr Muizzu's strong rhetoric
> against Delhi. It's a gap China is looking to exploit as the Asian
> powers jostle for influence in the region.
>
> Even then, Delhi and Male (the capital of the Maldives) managed to
> agree that Indian civilian technical staff would replace military
> troops to operate the aircraft - the first team has already reached
> the islands.

https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-68498232

The article hints that China can use the strategic location to monitor a crucial part of the Indian Ocean, and because it would allow China to observe India's movements, it could be a reason why it's geostrategically important for China, but I was wondering if there were other reasons why the region might be considered important geostrategically for China.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

China's navy is looking to be a world-wide one. China gets a lot of (vital) imports from Africa and the Middle East. It would make sense long term for them to have a naval base in that area--i.e. straddling the Arabian Sea and the Indian Ocean, even if they're currently denying they're planning that. (It would also [make sense](https://www.voanews.com/a/chinese-navy-in-nigeria-amid-base-concerns-/7169855.html) for them have a base even in *West* Africa, for that matter.)

"Pulling a Cuba" on India may also count as a plus for no other reason than embarrassing New Delhi, due to other geopolitical conflicts between India and China--territorial disputes on their common border etc. (The distance from the Maldives to the Indian coast is roughly in the same ballpark as that from Cuba to the US coast. Mkay, it might be 2x that, but you get the general idea.)

China is also making [inroads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China%E2%80%93Sri_Lanka_relations#Defense_ties) in Sri Lanka, which is even/substantially closer to India and larger. Having the Maldives and Sri Lanka compete in a way for Chinese favors/bases may be a plus in terms of getting concessions from at least one of these, if not both of them.

The Maldives also has a substantial EEZ, rich in fish.

[image]

And they also have a FTA with China [covering](https://v4.infofish.org/index.php/component/k2/item/144-maldives-the-free-trade-agreement-fta-between-china-and-maldives-will-generate-fresh-prospects-for-the-fisheries-industry) that. China also [has](https://seafood.media/fis/worldnews/worldnews.asp?monthyear=2-2024&day=8&id=128301&l=e&country=104&special=&ndb=1&df=0) a substantial distant-water fishing fleet. And Indian fishing boats [have](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwLTVIIIelk) sometimes come into conflict with the Maldive authorities (and vice-versa actually--their version of the cod wars, I guess.). Protecting the poor Maldive fishermen from Indian poachers could plausibly be an excuse for Chinese (armed) help in the region at some point. Even if armed just with water cannons at start, they [could](https://maritime-executive.com/article/video-chinese-water-cannon-breaks-bridge-windows-on-philippine-boat) prove influential.